# Php artisan migrate always exit with code 255

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have problems running the command php artisan migrate ( and all his variants)

When I type:

```
 migrate:install      
 migrate:refresh      
 migrate:reset        
 migrate:rollback
```

I get

```
 Process finished with exit code 255 at 16:25:30.
 Execution time: 969 ms.
```

The only one which works is:

```
php artisan migrate:status

+------+------------------------------------------------+
| Ran? | Migration                                      |
+------+------------------------------------------------+
| N    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table           |
| N    | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table |
| Y    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Association_table     |
| Y    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Club_table            |
| Y    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Competitor_table      |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Fight_table           |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Grade_table           |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Place_table           |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_ShiaiCategory_table   |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Shinpan_table         |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Team_table            |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171759_create_Tournament_table      |
| N    | 2015_11_01_171809_create_foreign_keys          |
| N    | 2015_11_02_182709_setup_countries_table        |
| N    | 2015_11_02_182710_charify_countries_table      |
+------+------------------------------------------------+

Process finished with exit code 0 at 16:27:00.
Execution time: 1,026 ms.
```

What can I do to run my queries???

One important fact, maybe, php artisan ... was working well in my Windows Computer.

Now, I have imported my git project in my mac, and doesn't work anymore.

Any Idea???

Comment: some of your migrations ran, is this because it was working at one point? Or the first time you ever tried to migrate those 3 worked and the rest did not?

Comment: Yesturday, on my windows computer, all my table were created ( like 10). I don't know why can't I even rollback!

Comment: but on your Mac, what did you do? ...meaning, what happens if you were to delete all the tables in your database and then run `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: I did php artisan migrate refresh / rollback. Thing is all the day I have been working on tables that are erased by now

Comment: please go and actually delete all the tables, not with `migrate refresh`, an actual delete of the tables. then try running `migrate` and say what happens

Comment: What data store are you using?

Comment: I deleted, then ran composer dump-autoload, and the run migrate refresh. It appears to be working now. Don't know what happened! Please put your comment as answer! Tx for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `php artisan migrate:status` shows that some of your migrations did in fact run. This leads me to believe that you don't really have an error, but just that something got messed up along the way when you were transferring things. Since Laravel is trying to keep track of your migrations, if things get out of sync it can cause problems.

Thus it is sometimes the simple reset that does the trick. However, running `php artisan migrate:rollback` doesn't fully reset your database, it leaves a `migrations` table.

To fully start over, just manually delete all the tables in your database, and then try running `php artisan migrate` over again, and it should work!