# How to solve the issue of laravel migration returning code 255?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7, laravel-migrations

I have installed laravel application and ran the first 'php artisan migrate' command that migrated the users table successfully. I then created other migrations for 2 more tables but when I run same command, I get this errors

Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

Process finished with exit code 255.

I have noted with other applications which were running, are also giving error when I run same command. What it the issue?

Comment: Does this help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510347/php-artisan-migrate-always-exit-with-code-255

Comment: Hi @shahidiqbal I have tried that solution but the command return the same error.

Comment: Try with this
php artisan migrate:fresh

Comment: php artisan migrate:fresh
Dropped all tables successfully.
Migration table created successfully.
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

Process finished with exit code 255.

Comment: Its reverting to the same point.

Comment: Run this command and see what does it shows. php artisan migrate:status

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231474/discussion-between-shahidiqbal-and-jaredkarl).